# Posts can be scrolled side to side in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, scrolling

On the Android app, you can scroll side to side in some posts (e.g. [this answer on Puzzle.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/37979/354)), which hides the first letter or two of each line.

Example:

[image: example]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: MotoE2(4G-LTE)

  - OS Version: 5.1 (2)

Comment: AFAIK, it's due to MathJax rendering. This can be easily reproduced on MathJax-intensive sites (e.g. [maths.se])